# FancyTree select to populate form from AJAX data

Tags: jquery, node.js, json, ajax, fancytree

I have implemented fancyTree which populates itself from JSON data,

I am trying to build it so when a file is selected in fancyTree, a HTML form is auto populated from the rest of the JSON data,

But I cant get it working

HTML Form:

```
    <div id="filter-form">
        <label for="filter-input">Filter:</label>
        <input type="text" id="filter-input" />
    </div>
    <div id="tree" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;"></div>

    <div id="drawingDetails">
        <form>
            <label for="Area">Area:</label>
            <input id="Area" name="Area">

            <label for="Category">Drawing Category:</label>
            <input id="Category" name="Category">

            <label for="Drawing_Number">Drawing Number:</label>
            <input id="Drawing_Number" name="Drawing_Number">

            <label for="Drawing_Sheet">Drawing Sheet:</label>
            <input id="Drawing_Sheet" name="Drawing_Sheet">

            <label for="Drawing_Rev">Drawing Rev:</label>
            <input id="Drawing_Rev" name="Drawing_Rev">

            <label for="DrawingDate">Drawing Revision Date:</label>
            <input id="DrawingDate" name="DrawingDate">

            <label for="DrawingDesc">Drawing Description:</label>
            <input id="DrawingDesc" name="DrawingDesc">

            <label for="Status">Drawing Status:</label>
            <input id="Status" name="Status">

        </form>
    </div>
```

```
        // Event handler for populating the form when selecting a file
        select: function (event, data) {
            var node = data.node;
            var nodeData = node.data || {}; // Initialize nodeData as an empty object

            if (node.isFolder()) {
                console.log("Folder Selected");
                // If a folder node is selected, clear the form fields
                $("#Area").val("");
                $("#Category").val("");
                $("#Drawing_Number").val("");
                $("#Drawing_Sheet").val("");
                $("#Drawing_Rev").val("");
                $("#DrawingDate").val("");
                $("#DrawingDesc").val("");
                $("#Status").val("");
            } else {
                console.log("Selected Node Data:", nodeData);

                // Populate the form with the node data
                $("#Area").val(nodeData.Area_Name);
                $("#Category").val(nodeData.Category_Name);
                $("#Drawing_Number").val(nodeData.Drawing_Number);
                $("#Drawing_Sheet").val(nodeData.Drawing_Sheet);
                $("#Drawing_Rev").val(nodeData.Revision_Number);
                $("#DrawingDate").val(nodeData.Revision_Date);
                $("#DrawingDesc").val(nodeData.Revision_Description);
                $("#Status").val(nodeData.Status_Code);
            }

            // Display the form field values
            console.log("Area:", $("#Area").val());
            console.log("Category:", $("#Category").val());
            console.log("Drawing Number:", $("#Drawing_Number").val());
            console.log("Drawing Sheet:", $("#Drawing_Sheet").val());
            console.log("Drawing Rev:", $("#Drawing_Rev").val());
            console.log("Drawing Date:", $("#DrawingDate").val());
            console.log("Drawing Description:", $("#DrawingDesc").val());
            console.log("Status:", $("#Status").val());

            // Add a debugger statement to pause the execution and inspect the variables
            debugger;
        },

        // ... other options and event handlers ...
    });

    // Fetch data from the server
    $.ajax({
        url: "/your-server-endpoint",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var treeData = processSQLResult(data);
            // Update the FancyTree source after fetching the data
            console.log(treeData); // Add this line to check the treeData
            $("#tree").fancytree("option", "source", treeData);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error("Failed to fetch data from the server:", error);
        },
    });
```

The fancyTree is working fine, but for some reasons selecting the files wont wont even display the console.log